# CloudFront InvalidArgument when Origin DomainName is a S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-cloudfront

I'm not able to use a previous created S3 Bucket (it's not a website S3 Bucket!) for one of my CloudFront Distribution Origins:

```
Error: error creating CloudFront Distribution: InvalidArgument: The parameter Origin DomainName does not refer to a valid S3 bucket.
    status code: 400, request id: xxxx

  on modules/cloudfront/main.tf line 20, in resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "app":
  20: resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "app" {
```

Notice: I successfully created a CloudFront Distribution with an Origin using the same S3 Bucket through the Web console to verify the S3 Bucket.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "static" {
    bucket = "static.any-domain.tld"
    acl = "public-read"
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "app" {
    enabled         = true
    is_ipv6_enabled = true
    comment         = "k8s test"

    # without this origin, cloudfront distribution is successfully created
    origin {
        # tried different dns domain names:
        # static.any-domain.tld.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
        # or static.any-domain.tld.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
        # or static.any-domain.tld.s3.amazonaws.com
        domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.static.bucket_regional_domain_name
        origin_id = "S3-${aws_s3_bucket.static.bucket}/any/path"
        origin_path = "/any/path"

        # tried with and without the following:
        s3_origin_config {
            origin_access_identity = "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${aws_cloudfront_distribution.app.id}"
        }
    }

    origin {
        domain_name = "any-valid-stuff.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
        origin_id   = "ELB-any-valid-stuff"

        custom_origin_config {
            origin_read_timeout = 30
            origin_keepalive_timeout = 30
            http_port = 80
            https_port = 443
            origin_protocol_policy = "http-only"
            origin_ssl_protocols = ["TLSv1"]
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I am currently running into exactly the same problem. Tried all sorts of domain names, didn't work at all

Comment: If it works from console, can you run aws cli [get-distribution-config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/get-distribution-config.html) to get details how the domain and other parameters are set?

Comment: @Marcin: I did and there is nothing wrong with my options :-(

Comment: Is it a new S3 bucket or an existing one?

Comment: @mokugo-devops testet with new and existing (via terraform import)

Comment: Can you enable debug logging in terraform and see what is being sent to AWS?  Maybe it’s a terraform bug?

Comment: A very strange behaviour! I guarantee that I haven't changed anything, but it works now with aws_s3_bucket.static.bucket_regional_domain_name as domain_name. Maybe a AWS issue on this day.